# HikariCP Connection Pool Tomcat debug enable

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, hikaricp

I am using Hikari Connection Pool in tomcat, We are getting timeout exception, where all connection are in active and there is not connection are available.

I want to enable debug logs for this in tomcat, Is there any steps to do this.

I tried `log4j.logger.com.zaxxer.hikari=DEBUG` in `log4j.properties`, it is not taking, I am not able to get the details in the console.

IS there any steps need to follow

Thanks
Mohsin

Comment: From your post it seems, you are logging with Log4J. HikariCP uses SLF4J. You need to add [slf4j-log4j12.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12) to your classpath, to redirect SLF4J loggings to Log4J.

Comment: i have added this jar file in lib folder of my web application, still not able to get the hikaricp debug information. Do you need to do some other settings

Comment: 2016-03-31 23:11:50,007 [pool-6-thread-1] DEBUG TransactionImpl:62 - committing
2016-03-31 23:11:50,008 [pool-6-thread-1] DEBUG LogicalConnectionManagedImpl:137 - Initiating JDBC connection release from afterTransaction
2016-03-31 23:11:50,008 [pool-6-thread-1] DEBUG PoolBase:205 -    testHikariCP - Reset (autoCommit) on connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@daccf86
2016-03-31 23:11:50,008 [pool-6-thread-1] DEBUG LogicalConnectionManagedImpl:137 - Initiating JDBC connection release from afterTransaction     I am getting this logs when i tried, not getting active connection total connection